# Xcode command line tools, as returned by 'xcode-select -p', are not from Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I am working on third party SDK(FolioReaderKit). When i install this `FolioReaderKit` pods I'm getting this bellow error.

**Error :**

> /bin/bash -c set -e sh build.sh cocoa-pods
>
> WARNING: The active Xcode command line tools, as returned by 'xcode-select -p', are not from Xcode.
>            The newest version of Xcode will be used instead.
>   Print: Entry, ":CFBundleVersion", Does Not Exist

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/
```

or open Xcode

Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations -> Command Line Tools set xcode

[image]

it should help.